# How to programmatically change button color - Android

Tags: android, xml

I have a button that I want to be round, so I made an xml file and set it as its background. The button is now round but I want to be able to change its color programmatically instead of hardcoding it into the xml file. How can I do this?

Here is my xml file for round button.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
           <solid android:color="#ffcb05"/>
      </shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
GradientDrawable backgroundShape = (GradientDrawable)btn.getBackground();
backgroundShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 10):

You can change color of view by using ColorFilter. It is very easy and quick.

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

This code will color button into red color.

Answer (score 2):

Try to get button background set color using getPaint :

```
((ShapeDrawable)yourbutton.getBackground()).getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToSet));
```